# How do Eddy Currents manage to "flow"?

Tags: current

I know, there's an overwhelming amount of information on the Internet about what eddy currents are, but on the fundamental front, I simply fail to grasp how currents could circulate/or even exist in a piece of metal. I always thought that in order for current to flow, conductors must be in different potentials. A solid piece of metal (if connected to a power source, say the positive terminal of an ac) would stay at
the same potential, with every spot on the metal at an equal potential. I can't imagine how current would flow within a block of conductor metal when all of the metal is a block.

Comment: "*A solid piece of metal (if connected to a power source, say the positive terminal of an ac) would stay at the same potential, with every spot on the metal at an equal potential.*" But does it really? What do you think an antenna is? Think about how you can charge up a conductor with static, then think about what AC is doing to your metal block at the close end and the far end whenever the amplitude or polarity changes.

Comment: Tea can flow in your teacup with a circular motion without a pressure difference driving it.

Comment: I can understand the tea in a teacup, as there's a path - the inner surface of the cup and the center kind of is ignored. But a conductor metal block, it has the same homogeneous conductivity everywhere.

Comment: Watch magnetic braking caused by eddy currents: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M856bqqbZcM

Comment: There are an infinite number of possible circular current paths within a block of conductor.

Comment: @Chu, well that's the problem. If there are infinite paths, why would the electrons need to flow at all? If, let's say that we magnify one such pathway of current, I reckon it would look like a piece of wire then. But, a conductor within a conductor is so confusing to me.

Comment: Currents will be induced in a conductor if it moves in a magnetic field, or if the magnetic field changes. What do you mean by 'a conductor within a conductor'?

Comment: @Chu, by "conductor within a conductor", I was referring to the path that these eddy currents would choose to take within the block of a conductor. Obviously, they don't flow everywhere, and they'll leave certain spots untouched.

Comment: A superconductor can have truly zero resistance but a circular loop can carry large currents.

Comment: It's anybody's guess what the current paths may be in a block of conductive material. We are normally only concerned with the measurable effects, such as forces that oppose motion, and heat generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't imagine how current would flow within a block of conductor metal when all of the metal is a block.

Imagine a loop of wire, surrounding a region of changing magnetic field. This loop of wire will have a voltage induced around it, and a current will flow through it.

If that region is air, then fill it in with metal. If that region is an iron core, then fuse the conductive loop to the core. Neither changes the conditions in the loop, you will still have current flow in response to the changing field across the inner region.

Comment: This was, by far, the best answer that I received so far. Thanks, I think I understand it now. This clears some of my doubts on "skin effect" as well, where the path of current flow is on the periphery of the conductor and no current flows in the center despite the conductor being a solid block of material.

Comment: Too add, once this conducting wire loop is fused to the core, an infinite number of new conductor loops suddenly appear and currents flow in all those loops simultaneously, right?

Answer (score 3):

> I always thought that in order for current to flow, conductors must be in different potentials.

This rule depends on a couple of simplifying assumptions that taken together are called the "lumped circuit approximation".

One of these assumptions is that there are no significant changing magnetic fields passing through the circuit. Without this assumption, we can't even actually define a potential at each point in a system.

But there are lots of situations where this assumption isn't valid. For example, in a magnetic generator, the internal working of the generator depends on the assumption being violated, even if we can still analyze the rest of the circuit outside the generator using lumped circuit analysis.

Similarly, eddy currents occur when changing magnetic fields excite currents in the metal. They don't depend on differences in potential because they come from the changing magnetic field, rather than from fields produced by electric charge. And those changing magnetic fields even mean the potential isn't well-defined in the regions where the eddy currents are found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I'm too naive (or perhaps haven't studied enough). I normally visualize current as something that flows in a path provided by a conductor. In a block of metal, since the whole metal is solid block where's the path, or how does the current choose its path of flow. And, weirdly, how do we measure such currents? Where do we connect our ammeter?

Comment: The current is flowing in every possible path at once, basically.

Comment: @Hearth, that what's confusing me from the beginning, on what basis is that current path chosen, since all of the material is conductive.

Comment: @BhanuNepal No current path is chosen--*all* paths are taken.

Comment: Which is also true when the current is driven by an electric potential difference. If you connect two wires together to form a branching circuit, current can and will flow in both wires, it doesn't just pick one. And microscopically, it flows more or less evenly through the whole cross-section of each wire, not just in a thin line down the center of the wire.

Comment: @ThePhoton, perhaps my problem is that I'm trying to visualize the current flow in the block of metal. Do electrons simply flow (or get disturbed actually) just like water would flow everywhere inside a washing machine?

Comment: @BhanuNepal The term that "The Photon" didn't mention is that this is called (by physicists teaching this to undergrads) a "non-Coulomb" electric field which ***curls*** around the region of changing flux. There is a 3D vector field. If you develop a *contour* of the vector field, you'll work out the connected loops that the electrons then follow. At each point in the 3D space, the electrons at that point *do* know which way to go. Often, layers of enameled metal are arranged so that the electrons are coerced to flow along a plane, instead.

Comment: @jonk, if this were the physics site, I'd have called it a "non-conservative" field. I've never heard it called "non-Coulomb" before.

Comment: @ThePhoton See "Matter & Interactions" by Chabay and Sherwood, any edition. And it is not "non-conservative" but instead "non-Coulomb."

Comment: @jonk, I'm not sure if you are trying to make a different point, but "non-conservative" is also used to describe the electric fields produced by changing magnetic fields. See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79254/non-conservative-field) for example.

Comment: @ThePhoton I was just referring to a specific textbook by physicists that uses the terminology I'm using above. But yes, looking at your link these are similar. The non-Coulomb electric field does perform "net work" when moving charges over a closed path. So it's non-conservative. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a great question. Here is my first attempt at an explanation.]

Its all about electric charges. [IMHO the "magnetic fluxes" hides behavior.
Perhaps the magnetic_potential would better explain issues. But I'm still learning about that.]

Or changes in charges. Which means changing voltages.

The sea-of-electrons, that is a metal, will move under the electric field of external charges.

As a sinusoidal voltage varies up and down in a wire near the surface of a metal plate, the local density of electrons at surface of the metal will --- slightly --- vary because of the externally applied electric field.

Does this matter? a thin piece of copper foil, your standard PCB foil thickness of 35 microns (1.4 mils) **has a propagation delay of 150 nanoseconds**, thru the foil from one side of the sheet to the other side.

This delay, 150 nanoSeconds, is about ONE MILLION times slower than light; thus ONE MILLION  times slower than charges move along the **surface** of the metal

These propagation delays become very pronounced for steel and iron, appearing at much lower frequencies (much longer delay times).

If you view the metal as filled with many **DELAY** regions, then nothing is happening instantaneously, anywhere.

All these delays of charge movement still need some balancing, so there is some requirement for transient-displaced charges to ---- eventually ---- return to their source within the sea-of-electrons.

I'm trying to understand the "eddy current" behavior myself.

I think the need for balancing, despite all the delays within the metal, cause the eddy current behavior.

[thank you for letting me try to answer this question.]

Comment: This answer can't possibly help someone with OP's level of understanding.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well, the propagation delay stuff helped me. Heh.

Comment: Well, I didn’t realize that this was an interesting question. I was actually ashamed to ask it here, but it drove me nuts when I tried to imagine how current would flow in a solid block of metal which is held at a constant potential; my notion of current flow was that it required ends to flow from and to, and a block of metal simply has no terminals.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf you mentioned “return to source”, and that confuses me further. The source of electrons is the metal block itself, and it doesn’t need to return anywhere at all.

Comment: @BhanuNepal Stop thinking of the block as one perfectly uniform, homogenous piece of material

Comment: Well then, how must I look at a block of metal then? What am I missing. Sorry for giving you guys a tough time, I guess I’m too dumb.

Comment: @DKNguyen, the answer has been updated since I commented.

Comment: @BhanuNepal The electric field is different in different parts of the material so current can flow from one part to another. It's not all the same everywhere just because it is the same piece of material. Different areas in the same material can be under different conditions.